# Code wont load to my attiny2313 microcontroller

Tags: avr, atmelstudio, avrdude, winavr

I connected the USBasp correctly and also updated the firmware.
no build error and after choosing USBasp as tool, it says avrdud is ready but my led wont turn on.

this is what appears after loading with USBasp:

```
avrdude.exe: set SCK frequency to 32000 Hz
avrdude.exe: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude.exe: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s
avrdude.exe: Device signature = 0x1e910a
avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.
```

I am using atmel studio 7 and laptop is windows 10 64bits

Comment: Please explain it more, which led" is not turn on? is it led on your MCU or led in USBasp. If you mean led on MCU, please post the code, no error on build does not mean you code is right, but if it is led on USBasp, maybe you should check your wiring.

Answer (score 0):

The "warning: cannot set sck period" message can normally safely be ignored - It's a message that used to be given with the original "Fischl" hardware.
According to the `avrdude` messages, your code was properly received, checksummed and programmed.

Presumably, something else is wrong with your program or hardware.